# WSO2 Governance Registry not publishing Service into WSO2 API Manager

Tags: web-services, wso2, wso2-governance-registry

On "publish" button click (current service state "Production") I am getting below error in WSO2 Governance Registry console.

> Failed to invoke aspect: An exception occurred while executing handler chain. APIManager endpoint URL or credentials are not definedAPI Publish might fail**

Below is my WSO2 Gov reg configuration as described in this [link](https://docs.wso2.org/display/AM160/Integrating+with+WSO2+Governance+Registry+Services).

```
<state id="Production">
                <datamodel>
                    <data name="transitionExecution">
                        <execution forEvent="Demote" class="org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.executors.DemoteActionExecutor">
                        </execution>
                        <execution forEvent="Publish" class="org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.executors.apistore.ApiStoreExecutor">
                                <parameter name="apim.endpoint" value="http://localhost:9763/store"/>
                                <parameter name="apim.username" value="admin"/>
                                <parameter name="apim.password" value="admin"/>
                                <parameter name="default.tier" value="Unlimited"/>
                                <parameter name="throttlingTier" value="Unlimited,Unlimited,Unlimited,Unlimited,Unlimited"/>
                        </execution>
                    </data>
                </datamodel>
                <transition event="Publish" target="Published.to.APIStore"/>
                <transition event="Demote" target="Testing"/>
            </state>
            <state id="Published.to.APIStore">                   
            </state>
```

**Stack trace:**

> [2014-03-06 15:43:30,623] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.governance.custom.lifecycles.checklist.util.InvokeAspectUtil} -  Failed to invoke action Publish of aspect Service
>   LifeCycle on resource /_system/governance/branches/production/services/com/w3schools/www/webservices/1.2.0/Temp_Convert_Service. An exception occurred while execut
>   ing handler chain. APIManager endpoint URL or credentials are not definedAPI Publish might fail
>   org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: An exception occurred while executing handler chain. APIManager endpoint URL or credentials are not def
>   inedAPI Publish might fail
>           at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.invokeAspect(HandlerManager.java:2814)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.invokeAspect(HandlerLifecycleManager.java:542)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.invokeAspect(EmbeddedRegistry.java:2550)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.invokeAspect(CacheBackedRegistry.java:384)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.invokeAspect(UserRegistry.java:1395)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.governance.custom.lifecycles.checklist.util.InvokeAspectUtil.invokeAspect(InvokeAspectUtil.java:52)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.governance.custom.lifecycles.checklist.services.LifecyclesAdminService.invokeAspect(LifecyclesAdminService.java:47)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

This [link in WSO2 docs](https://docs.wso2.org/display/AM160/Integrating+with+WSO2+Governance+Registry+Services) affirms that you have to modify /repository/resources/lifecycles/configurations.xml, but I think this is *incorrect*. Infact in Greg 4.6.0 this file is no more used. Another version of it is stored in a small db and you **MUST make changes from GReg administration console** just go to *Extensions->Configure->Lifecycles* and edit **ServiceLifeCycle** with your APIM parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Use G-Reg version 5.0.0 and above and API manager 1.9.0 or 1.9.1. Refer the following documentation

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Integrating+with+WSO2+Governance+Registry

Thanks

Prasanna

Answer (score 0):

For apim endpoint use `http://localhost:9763/` only instead of `http://localhost:9763/store.`

Comment: Tried with that.. also tried to replace ip instead localhost.. It's same exception coming...

Comment: WHat is the GReg and AM version you are using ?

Comment: wso2am-1.6.0, wso2greg-4.6.0

Comment: As far as I remember there were some issues with regard to AM 1.6 compatibility with GReg 4.6.0. But this worked fine with AM 1.5. Give it a try with AM 1.5. It should work.